# How can I get the ratio between the areas?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a statement that says:

> If a rectangle increases its width by one fifth of its length and its
>   length decreases it in half, then its initial area will:

The answer must be: **Decreases $2/5$ of the initial area.**

So my development was:

$w_1*L_1 = A_1$

$w_2 = w_1 + L_1/5$

$L_2 = L_1/2$

So, $A_2 = (w_1 + L_1/5)(L_1/2)$

$A_2 = (w_1L_1)/2 + (L_1)^2/2$

Then, $A_2/A_1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{L}{5W_1}$

But the answer must be purely numerical, in which I am failing or how do I arrive at the result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I _suspect_ that the statement has been garbled somewhere and that "length" has two meanings - the size of the width and the length of the rectangle. (The commas are weird.) Then the area would change by a factor of $1.2 \times 0.5 = 0.6$.

Comment: Ethan, how you know that?

Comment: Your answer supports @Ethan Bolker's reading of the problem.  If the area decreases by $2/5$ you are left with $0.6$ of the original area.

Comment: How ? Can you explain me, please?

Comment: He is saying $w_2=1.2w_1$.  The first "length" is the length of the short side, not the length of the rectangle.  I think the wording is very confusing.

Comment: Also do you *want* the initial area (which is asked for) or the new area.  It's rather important to actually *ask* a question and be specific about what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the edit providing the answer, it's very likely that (as in my comment) the question was garbled somewhere, or was just badly written. The statement

> If a rectangle increases its width by one fifth of its length and its
>   length decreases it in half, then its initial area will:

means

> If the width of a rectangle increases by one fifth of itself and the
>   length decreases to half of itself then ...

... the width and length of the new rectangle are $1.2W$ and $0.5L$. Multiplying those together (to find the area) shows that the area has changed by a factor 
$1.2 \times 0.5 = 0.6$. So the new area is $60\%$ of the original area. It has decreased by $2/5$ of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is sound and there is no single number that is the ratio of areas.  You can just take a couple rectangles to show the example.  Let rectangle $1$ be $2 \times 100$ with area $200$.  It changes to $22 \times 50$ with area $1100$ so the ratio is $5.5$.  Let rectangle $2$ be $10 \times 10$ with area $100$.  It changes to $12 \times 5$ with area $60$ so the ratio is $0.6$

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean with "it changes to..$

Comment: I just followed the text and your calculation.  For rectangle $1$ the width starts out $2$ and increases by $\frac {100}5=20$  The length starts out $100$ and decreases to $\frac {100}2=50$

Comment: Well, but the answer should be: Decreases 2/5 of the initial area.

Comment: I already edited the question, see now please

Answer (score 0):

$A_2 = (w_1 + \frac{L_1}{5})(\frac{L_1}{2})$

$A_2 = \frac{(w_1L_1)}{2} + \frac{(L_1)^2}{10}$

$\frac{A_2}{A_1} = \frac{(w_1L_1)}{2(w_1L_1)} + \frac{(L_1)^2}{10(w_1L_1)}$

$$\frac{A_2}{A_1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{L_1}{10w_1}$$

Increasing the width by one fifth of the length negates this from being an increase in area by a constant factor.

To decrease by $\frac{2}{5}$of the original area, the width increasing by one fifth and the length decreasing by one half is one possible solution.